# Exclude Category From wp_get_archives?

Tags: wordpress, categories, archive

Is there any way to exclude a category from wp_get_archives? I'm trying to show the months in the sidebar, but I want to exclude the posts that are not blog entries.

```
$catID = get_cat_id('Projects');
$variable = wp_get_archives('type=monthly&show_post_count=1);
echo $variable;
```

Answer (score 5):

Use this if you want to include only specific categories for wp_get_archive function in your functions.php of your theme directory

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'customarchives_where' );
add_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'customarchives_join' );

function customarchives_join( $x ) {

    global $wpdb;

    return $x . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)";

}

function customarchives_where( $x ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $includes= '14'; // category id to include
    return $x . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = '$includes'";

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a filter in your functions.php file which will change wp_get_archive function's default behavior.

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'customarchives_where' );
add_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'customarchives_join' );

function customarchives_join( $x ) {

    global $wpdb;

    return $x . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)";

}

function customarchives_where( $x ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $exclude = '1'; // category id to exclude

    return $x . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id NOT IN ($exclude)";

}
```

Comment: copy-pasted into my functions.php 6 years later and it still works!

Comment: actually, I take it back. This only works if the post has *only* that excluded category, and no others.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this problem in a project but never found a solution online -- mine isn't the prettiest PHP, but it does the trick.

This is a play off the filter suggested by Katie, which I ran across in few support forums as well. This goes in your `functions.php`:

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'customarchives_where' );
add_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'customarchives_join' );

function customarchives_join( $x ) {

    global $wpdb;

    return $x . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) 
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)";

}

function customarchives_where( $x ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $categories = get_terms( 'taxonomy-name', 'orderby=id' );
    $includeIds;
    $i = 0;
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        if($i != 0) $includeIds .= ',';
        $includeIds .= $category->term_id;
        $i++;
    } 


    return $x . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'taxonomy-name' 
    AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($includeIds)";

}
```

In the second function, swap `taxonomy-name` for the name of your actual custom taxonomy.

All the IDs of terms in your custom taxonomy are captured in a string; the rest operates the same as the original function -- only that list of categories from your custom taxonomy are included in the `wp_get_archives()` list. You can also tweak the code to exclude them as well (first example above).

If you only want one instance of the `wp_get_archives()` list to do this, just skip the top two lines of code in your `functions.php` that apply the filters. Then, when you use the `wp_get_archives()` tag, apply the filters before it, and remove them afterwards:

```
<?php   
add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'customarchives_where' );
    add_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'customarchives_join' );

    wp_get_archives(); 

    remove_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'customarchives_where' );
    remove_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'customarchives_join' );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`wp_get_archives()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_get_archives) does not have a mechanism to exclude based on category -- it's purely for time-based archives (yearly, monthly, daily, weekly) or "every post" archives: postbypost or post by post ordered by post title.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to work with category archives: [WordPress › Support » Limit archives to category / date archives for category](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/278299?replies=8)

I use Clean Archives Reloaded [WordPress › Clean Archives Reloaded « WordPress Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/clean-archives-reloaded/) and exclude categories around line 200:

```
// Get a simple array of all posts
$rawposts = get_posts( 'numberposts=-1&category=-4,-6,-7,-9' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in to [get_categories](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_categories) and lean towards your own custom solution. While this may cost you a little more time and work; you will indeed get the upshot of having full control over what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a filter hook on pre_get_posts instead?

I know something like this works for is_author, is_home, and is_feed...

```
function exclude_stuff($query) { 
    if ( $query->is_author) {
        $query->set('cat', '-4, -142');
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'exclude_stuff');
```

depends on whether you can do it for something like is_archive or is_monthly

You would drop that in a php file with a plugin header:

```
<?php
/*
 * Plugin Name: exclude some stuff
 * Description: blah
 * Author: blah
 * Plugin URI: blah
 * Version: 0.9
 * =======================================================================
*/
   Put the function here
?>
```

Then upload it to your Plugins directory and activate it.

Answer (score 0):

Place the code below just after 
This code is working for me already :)

```
<?php
if ( $wp_query->is_archive ){
$wp_query->query_vars["cat"] = 14; // only the category that you want to inlcude
$wp_query->query_vars["posts_per_page"] = 10; // for number of posts you want
$wp_query->get_posts();}
?>
```

Comment: This works for the main loop, not the wp_get_archives() function

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an official way of doing this. But i tried and tested a lot of code block and only this one worked for me.

```
    add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'customarchives_where' );
add_filter( 'getarchives_join', 'customarchives_join' );

function customarchives_join( $x ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $x . " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)";
}

function customarchives_where( $x ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $include = 'your_category_id'; // category id to include
    return $x . " AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category' AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id IN ($include)";
}
```

Replace your_category_id with an original id of your post category and the code will work.