# Wordpress yearly archives for current category

Tags: wordpress, function, filter, archive

This has really been driving me mad for a while now, so I'm hoping someone can help. I'm trying to use `wp_get_archives()` to display a list of links to yearly archives *that show posts within the current category*.

Importantly, I'm trying to do this **without** a plugin and just use the functions file or even a `WP_Query` loop.

**Example**

Imagine I have the following categories all filled with posts:

Exhibitions (parent)
--Current (child)
--Past (child)

Artworks (parent)
--Recent (child)
--Featured (child)
--Old (child)

What I'm trying to do is essentially this:

```
/* Get current Cat ID */
function getCurrentCatID() {
    global $wp_query;
    if(is_category() || is_single()){
        $cat_ID = get_query_var('cat');
    }
    return $cat_ID;
}

$currentCat = getCurrentCatID();

wp_get_archives('type=yearly&cat=$currentCat'); // But, you can't filter this by category it seems
```

So, if I view the 'Exhibitions' category (which uses category.php), `wp_get_archives()` would show links for 2012, 2011, 2010 etc.

When I click 2011, I would see posts that are in the category 'Exhibitions' AND it's child categories (also important).

I've found this post which might hold the answer: [Exclude Category From wp_get_archives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789228/exclude-category-from-wp-get-archives)

But I don't know how I would use the current category being viewed within filters mentioned in the post nor how I would add multiple categories to it (i.e. the parent category plus it's children).

Any help massively appreciated.

Osu

Answer (score 0):

The way I read this, there's two facets to this question. The first has to do with generating and printing links. But there's also the matter of those links leading to URLs that exist. This might help with that second bit:

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/per-category-date-archives-not-working

I used it sucessfully once to generate "/category/date/" style URLs.